# How to exclude some processes while using ps command

Tags: command-line, python3

I try to develop Task manager for my personal use using python3.
In my code I use this command to list all running process in a while loop

```
ps -eo pid,comm,user,%mem,%cpu | awk '{$4=<Variablehere>*$4/100;}{print;}'
```

but each time it is executed there are three processes I don't want them to be listed which are `sh` `ps` `awk`

so my question is, how can I get the PIDs of these processes so that I can later get rid of them from the list

thanks

**[EDIT]**

```
import subprocess
from time import sleep
```

class processData :
    def  **init** (self) :
        mem = next(self._run_command("m")).decode('utf-8').replace("\n","")
        mem = str(int(float(mem)/1024))
        #print(mem)

`self.allprocess = "ps -eo pid,comm,user,%mem,%cpu | awk '{$4="+mem+"*$4/100;}{print;}';"
        self.ownprocess = "ps -eo pid,comm,user,%mem,%cpu | awk '{$4=(" + mem + "*$4/100);}{print;}' | grep $USER"
        self.otherprocess = "ps -eo pid,comm,user,%mem,%cpu | awk '{$4=(" + mem + "*$4/100);}{print;}' | grep -v $USER"

    def _run_command(self,fil):
        if fil   == "a" : command = self.allprocess
        elif fil == "u" : command = self.ownprocess
        elif fil == "o" : command = self.otherprocess
        elif fil == "m" : command = "awk '/MemTotal/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo"
        p = subprocess.Popen(command,
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                             shell=True)
        for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
            if line:
                yield line
        while p.poll() is None:                                                                                                                                        
            sleep(.1)
        err = p.stderr.read()
        if p.returncode != 0:
           print("Error: " + str(err))


    @staticmethod
    def unique(list1 , list2) :
        ids = [i[0] for i in list2]
        return [i for i in list1 if i[0] not in ids];

    def get(self,choice) :
        processes = [];
        for process in self._run_command(choice) :

            processes.append(process.decode('utf-8').replace("\n","").split());
        return processes#[0:(len(processes)-1)-2];

print(processData().get("a"));`

What I want is not to list any processes that is running due to the running of my program

Comment: Have you considered using one of the existing python APIs such as [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) or [proc](https://pypi.org/project/proc/) instead of shelling out to a `ps` command?

Comment: @steeldriver thanks a lot I will take a look at them

Comment: @steeldriver Please make it an Answer to accept it, it's very useful

Answer (score 0):

Just insert the condition `$2 !~ /^(awk|sh|ps)$/`:

```
ps -eo pid,comm,user,%mem,%cpu | awk '$2 !~ /^(awk|sh|ps)$/ {$4=<Variablehere>*$4/100;}{print;}'
```

It means "if $2 does not match *start-of-string*, followed by either `awk`, `sh`, or `ps`, followed by *end-of-string*" then ...

Comment: I don't want to block any `sh` `ps` `awk` , I want to block them in that process using their PIDs 
thanks for your reply

Comment: Then swap the condition by replacing `!~` with `~`.

Comment: Please take a look on my question edit